# the content of the params[:input] changes without doing any modification in nested loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters

this is the code.I don't see any problem.Everything works fine for the first device but for other devices no gsub happens since after sending the push when I tried to change the content of @data back to the params[:message], they are the same.

I don't know how but params[:message] changed from its original content just like data.

can you guys point my fault?

One more question;is there any other way to do this string substitution, a more efficient way?

```
  def omg   # send all
    @devices= Device.all 

    @devices.each  do |device|  #one device

#"attribute"=>[".last_name", ".nickname"], 
#"message"=>"sadf.nickname.last_name", "commit"=>"checkbox test"}
#checkbox ticked[".last_name", ".nickname"]
#attributes icerigi bu [".last_name", ".nickname"]

    @attributeArray = params[:attribute] #checed values.


    @attributeArray.each do |attribute|
      #logger.info device.send(attribute) #device.first_name  

     logger.info "first params message"  + params[:message]

     @data= params[:message]


    @data.gsub!(attribute, device.send(attribute))



     end

    APNS.send_notification(device.token.to_s, @data )

      @data =params[:message]

        logger.info "params message"  + params[:message]
        logger.info  "data after push " + @data 
        logger.info "payload" + @data
    end

   redirect_to home_index_path

   end
```

EDIT:

```
def omg   # send all
    @devices= Device.all 

    @devices.each  do |device|  #tek bir cihaz

#"attribute"=>[".last_name", ".nickname"], 
#"message"=>"sadf.nickname.last_name", "commit"=>"checkbox test"}
#checkbox ticked[".last_name", ".nickname"]
#attributes icerigi bu [".last_name", ".nickname"]

    @attributeArray = params[:attribute] #check edilmis valueler.


    @attributeArray.each do |attribute|
      #logger.info device.send(attribute) #device.first_name  

     logger.info "params messaji ilk bu  bu"  + params[:message]

     data= params[:message]

    #logger.info @data.gsub([nickname, attribute=> device.send(attribute) )  

    mahmut =data.gsub!(attribute, device.send(attribute))
    logger.info  "mahmut icerigi" + mahmut

    logger.info " baska data bu " + mahmut

    @payloadBoddy = mahmut

     end

    APNS.send_notification(device.token.to_s, @payloadBoddy )

        #@data =" "

        logger.info "params messaji bu"  + params[:message]
        logger.info  "push sonrasi data " + @payloadBoddy 
        logger.info "data bu " + @payloadBoddy
    end

   redirect_to home_index_path

   end
```

i changed the code a bit.

now it works for couple of devices but only for one attribute.

wow what am i missing

Comment: Well you are mutating params[:message] with gsub!. Not entirely sure what you're trying to do though

Comment: i m mutating data, not params[:message] ?

Comment: They're the same object

Comment: @FrederickCheung i tried to differentiate them but it didn't help either, how can i do this correctly?In objective c or any other language that i use, the right side of the equation doesn't change when you equalize it with another variable

Comment: Pretty much everything is effectively a pointer in ruby - in objective c foo = bar doesn't create a new NSString for example

Comment: @FrederickCheung yea i m 1 week old in ruby :) do you have any solution ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
@attributeArray.each do |attribute|
  logger.info "first params message"  + params[:message]
  @data= params[:message]
  @data.gsub!(attribute, device.send(attribute))
end
```

Do:

```
@data = params[:message].dup

@attributeArray.each do |attribute|
  logger.info "first params message"  + params[:message]
  @data.gsub!(attribute, device.send(attribute))
end
```

Comment: it works for one attribute when i don't use gsub! but if there are multiple attributes it just gsub the last attribute

Comment: C strings are totally mutable

Comment: @FrederickCheung - Don't know C very well, assumed it will be the same as c#. Removed.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
@data = params[:message]
```

Then `@data` is just a reference to the same ruby object as `params[:message]`, so when you use `gsub!` on it you are mutating `params[:message]`. It's not entirely clear to me what you are doing, but it looks like you are using `params[:message]` as some sort of template that you are filling in with various attribute values.

You're actually relying on this behaviour since you're setting @data each iteration through the attributes loop. The simplest solution is to duplicate the message before the loop, ie

```
@payloadBody = params[:message].dup
@attributeArray.each do |attribute|
  @data.gsub!(attribute, device.send(attribute))
end    
APNS.send_notification(device.token.to_s, @payloadBody )
```

Lastly be wary about using the value of a user supplied parameter (params[:attribute]) in a call to `send`. For example, what if they had passed `destroy`. You'll also make your questions easier to answer if you simplify your code down to a minimal example that exhibits the problems - dozens of commented out lines or logging calls are just clutter

Comment: params[:attribute] are user supplied but they are coming from a checkbox, can it be modified?

Comment: Anything coming from the user is modifiable

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
data = params[:message]
```

You are not creating a new object - just giving a new name to the same one. If you don't want to modify it, you can ask for a copy first:

```
data = params[:message].dup
```

You can then gsub is all you want without impacting the original param.

Comment: this solution works for one attribute, but i ll have more than one attribute